# This website can't be reached

Tags: server, apache2, php

I just installed wordpress to vps server. I'm using ubuntu 16.04 at server. I already installed `lamp`  and configured them.

But still server doesn't show any php file. When I create index.html and say "it works". I'm able to see this at browser..

I checked apache logs there is no error record and tried to `curl localhost` it doesn't show any error too..

But still browser says this site can't be reached.. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Did you install the php module for apache?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen yes I did

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen  `/var/www/html# sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-fpm php7.0-mysql -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php7.0 is already the newest version (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
php7.0 set to manually installed.
php7.0-mysql is already the newest version (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).`

Comment: Please install this `sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.0` and restart apache!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen it'S already installed too, `libapache2-mod-php7.0 is already the newest version`

Comment: Run `ls -l /var/www/html` lets see the permissions

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen https://imgur.com/a/YE8H8NJ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83773/discussion-between-george-udosen-and-hasan-tingir).